# Есть ли в предложении уточнение

Tags: пунктуация

*Именно здесь(,) в холоде и голоде(,) родился у него план*. Выделенный оборот — уточнение, или здесь не нужны запятые?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Выделенный оборот** — ***уточнение, запятые здесь нужны*.** Легко можно представить себе это предложение без уточнения: **Именно здесь родился у него план**. Фраза ***в холоде и голоде*** имеет уточняющий смысл и обособляется запятыми.